# How to display API map via Ajax with a return json list

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, google-maps

I have a jsp page which shows all the fastfoods nearby my location by google maps API. I would like to make a javascript with ajax that will display fastfoods with  marks in the map and the table.

This javascript is connected by url with a servlet that returns fast foods information in a json list( name, street, phone number, longitude, latitude). But I don't know what to write in the success area for displaying them.

My code for js is :

```
function getNearestFastFood(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'myservlet',
    type: 'json',
    data: {
       latitude: pos[0],
       longitude: pos[1]
    },
    success: function(data){
        //display my map and also a table with the closest fast foods
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Have you had trouble making a javascript with ajax? On a serious note, you will just need to plot the points on the map. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/pGBZD/) that does what you want (it just has all the locations at once, whereas you will plot them once you receive them via `success: function(data){ }`). You don't include anything regarding this mysterious table of yours, but that should be sufficient information